# Switch fragments after every 5 seconds using view pager android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i m using view pager to slide the fragments by finger using viewpager in android. its working fine but now i want to do that if user does not touch the screen it automatically changes the fragment to next after every few seconds. kindly help me how to do that.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class AutoSwitcherViewPager extends ViewPager {



    private Runnable  mSwither = new Runnable() {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
         * @since Jun 13, 2013
         * @author rajeshcp
         */
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if( AutoSwitcherViewPager.this.getAdapter() != null )
            {
                int count = AutoSwitcherViewPager.this.getCurrentItem();

                if( count ==  (AutoSwitcherViewPager.this.getAdapter().getCount() - 1) )
                {
                    count = 0;
                }else
                {
                    count++;
                }

                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Curent Page  " + count + "");
                AutoSwitcherViewPager.this.setCurrentItem(count, true);
            }
            AutoSwitcherViewPager.this.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };


    /**
     * @param context  
     * @return of type AutoSwitcherViewPager
     * Constructor function
     * @since Jun 13, 2013 
     * @author rajeshcp
     */
    public AutoSwitcherViewPager(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs  
     * @return of type AutoSwitcherViewPager
     * Constructor function
     * @since Jun 13, 2013 
     * @author rajeshcp
     */
    public AutoSwitcherViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        postDelayed(mSwither, 5000);
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.view.ViewPager#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)
     * @since Jun 13, 2013
     * @author rajeshcp
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            postDelayed(mSwither, 5000);
            break;

        default:
            removeCallbacks(mSwither);
            break;
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(arg0);
    }



}
```

Use this class as your `ViewPager`

```
<packagename.AutoSwitcherViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Replace the `<packagename` with your `AutoSwitcherViewPager` class package

Comment: yes its switching the fragment in any case after specific time if user manually slides the screen or not. i want to switch if user doesnot manually slides the fragment.

Comment: its working same as it was before. where do we have to intialize autoswichter class in the postdelayed ?

Comment: You can use the class as viewpager inside your layout and remove the other code what I posted early.

Comment: i m not geting your point how to use this class in layout ? kindly help

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

  
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />


</RelativeLayout>

Comment: See the edited answer. Make sure you give the exact package name

Comment: It Worked Thanks.